# Starting a project with Stanford C++ Libraries in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation

I'm trying to follow along with the Stanford CS106B course.  They provide some libraries for use in the course but I can't for the life of me start and new project, import the libraries and get it to compile.

These are the errors im getting. Not sure how helpful they are...

> ld: duplicate symbol _main in
>   /Users/adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_2-d
>   hgxptnyygirinbntlelnegvower/Build/Intermediates/Chapter
>   2.build/Debug/Chapter 2.build/Objects-normal/i386/task11.o and /Users/adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_2-dhgxptnyygirinbntlelnegvower/Build/Intermediates/Chapter
>   2.build/Debug/Chapter 2.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o for architecture i386
>
> Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does `task11.cpp` (or whatever compiles to `task11.o`) have a `main` function? I assume there's one in `main.o` as well. Are you sure they're supposed to be linked together, and they're not seperate programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have 2 `main()` functions in the application that you are trying to compile.**

One is in `task11.o` and another one in `main.o`.
Your application can have only one main function so remove one - not sure what exactly you are doing and which one is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, there was another function in my 'supporting files' that had a main function. Deleting the file fixed the error.